# Run a SQL Server procedure from Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. I created a procedure in one database. The procedure is composed of several queries to different databases and the final combined result set is being displayed.

I try to execute it via Excel, so the results will appear automatically in Excel sheet, but I'm getting the error:

> The query did not run, or the database table could not be opened. Check the database server or contact your DBA. Make sure the external database is available and hasn't been moved or recognized, then try the operation again

I created a simpler procedure that queries only one database, and the results displayed at the Excel sheet with no issues.

Hence I suspect that, the original procedure failed due to the fact that I'm querying several databases in the procedure, when in the connection details of the "External Data Properties", only one database is mentioned.

My question is - can it be solved? Can I use multiple databases in the procedure and see it in the Excel?

Thanks, 
Roni

Comment: this can be helpfull for you.                                                                  http://blogs.office.com/2010/06/07/running-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-excel-no-vba/

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I'm doing. 

If the Procedure only query data from one DB - the one that mentioned in the Connection details, then there's no problem. When there are multiple databases in the queries inside the procedure, then I'm getting the error.

Comment: Are all the databases on the same server? Does the sql login or user on the excel connection string have access to each of the databases?  Does the stored proc return more than one result set?  If you are able to run the stored procedure in ssms without issue, try using your credentials to setup the connection in excel.

Comment: 1. All the DBs on the same server. 2.The user has access permissions for the tables in the DB. 3.There's only 1 result set. 4. I've ran the procedure in SSMS with no issue and got the required result set. 5. I tried to change the user to a more powerful one. I still got the error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I transformed the procedure to have Table Variables instead of Temporary tables and I've added "set nocount on" to the beginning of the procedure.

The second action solved the issue.

The first action improved the response time of the procedure.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Roni Vered, It helped.

Comment: @Roni Vered did you find why did the Set NOCOUNT ON solved your issue?

Answer (score 2):

(Copying key parts of @Roni's answer)

```
create procedure dbo.xxx
as

set nocount on
...
```

Comment: If proc contains temp tables, also  record 'SET NOCOUNT OFF' should be placed before 'END' ... or SET NOCOUNT may be missed at all,